# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException while connecting Cassandra DB

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I was trying out a simple connection to my Cassandra instance through Java. I made a 'demo' keyspace to cqlsh and created a table in the java program. The code is below:

Jars Used:

- slf4j.api-1.6.1
- cassandra-all-2.1.2

  ```
  public class CassandraConnection {

      public static void main(String[] args){

          String ipAddress="127.0.0.1";
          String keySpace="demo";

          Cluster cluster;

          Session session;

          cluster=Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(ipAddress).build();

          session=cluster.connect(keySpace);

          System.out.println("====================Before insert");

          String cqlInsertStmt="insert into users (lastname,age,city,email,firstname) values"
          +"('Gopalan',32,'Paramakkudi','murugan@gmail.com','Murugan') ";

          session.execute(cqlInsertStmt);

          String cqlSelectStmt="select * from users";
          ResultSet resultSet=session.execute(cqlSelectStmt);

          System.out.println("=================After insert");

          for(Row row: resultSet){

              System.out.format("%s %s %d %s %s \n", row.getString("firstname"),row.getString("lastname"),row.getInt("age"),row.getString("city"),row.getString("email"));
          }

          System.out.println("=================After update");

      }
  }
  ```

I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:60)
    at CassandraConnection.main(CassandraConnection.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:60)
    at CassandraConnection.main(CassandraConnection.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make sure that the **logback** JAR is within your classpath.

See [here](https://logback.qos.ch/download.html) for starters; and beyond that; the real take-away here: the runtime is telling you that it can't find a certain class; and it gives you the **full** name of that class. Or you look [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configLoggingLevels_r.html) to read what Cassandra has to say about logback.

You take that input; and then you turn to your favorite search engine in order to figure what is going on.

Answer (score 11):

The root cause of this issue is the required jars not being available in the CLASSPATH. Please add the following dependencies - they will solve your issue.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: my case was caused an empty jar file in .m2 which I suspect appeared when maven (3.5.2) was building without access to artifactory behind vpn